# Eclipse - How to change the color of the "matching word assist"?

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to change the color of the "matching word assist". I don't know the proper name, but it's a function that highlights the selected word and all its repetitions (for example highlight all the "var" variable names when selected.

Can you tell me the name of this property and where is in Eclipse preferences so I can change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of that property is `Ocurrences`, and you can change it on Preferences by going to:

`General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations`

As you can see here:

[image: Ocurrences]

Also, change the `Write Ocurrences` for when variables have their value assigned or changed.